# Mapping a nested array of objects in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to display a list of items with variations based on one of its object. See the code below for some insight:

```js
data: [{
  "transportation": [
    {"id": "1", "name": "bus", "type": "large"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "bicycle", "type": "small"}],
    
  "animal": [
    {"id": "3", "name": "elephant", "type": "large"},
    {"id": "4", "name": "mouse", "type": "small"}]
 }]
```

For the example above, I would like to display lets say something simple like "Large" text if the type is "large" and "Small" text if the type is "small. The first thing come to my mind is to do a nested map (outer map for data, inner map for transportation/animal). I started off by testing the inner map first without the outer map, as illustrated below:

```js
data.animal.map((info) => {
  switch (info.type){
    case "large":
      return(
        <View>
        <Text>Large</Text>
        </View>);

    case "small":
      return(
       <View>
       <Text>Small</Text>
       </View>);
         
    default:
      return(
        <View>
        <Text>Whatever</Text>
        </View>);
  }
})
```

I got

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Any idea why does this happens?

**EDIT:**

I had tried to do a nested loop while waiting for an answer. Below is my code snippet:

```js
data.map((category, key) => {
  return(
    Object.keys(category).map((info) => {
    switch (info.type){
    case "large":
    return(
    <View>
    <Text>Large</Text>
    </View>);
    
    case "small":
    return(
    <View>
    <Text>Small</Text>
    </View>);
    
    default:
    return(
    <View>
    <Text>Whatever</Text>
    </View>);
 }
   })
  )
})
```

It runs without error, but it doesn't give me the expected result. All the output are switched to default i.e. "Whatever".

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the first object of your data array. So your code should be

```
data[0].animal.map((info) => {
....
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    data = [{
  "transportation": [
    {"id": "1", "name": "bus", "type": "large"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "bicycle", "type": "small"}],
    
  "animal": [
    {"id": "3", "name": "elephant", "type": "large"},
    {"id": "4", "name": "mouse", "type": "small"}]
 }]


data[0].animal.map((info) => {
   return console.log(info)
  }
)
```